# How do I know which chipset a motherboard uses?

Tags: motherboard, integrated-graphics, chipset

I am building a new computer and am curious about the chipsets that motherboards use and I found it quite confusing because it gives me two values

The motherboard I've chosen is the MSI Z87-G41 ATX LGA1150 Motherboard

So it uses the Z87 chipset? But it also says G41? What is the difference between them?

I want to overclock the processor AND use integrated graphics with it. Is that possible?

Sorry if I sound silly, this is my first build and I want it to work. I'm not using a video card with it at the moment

Comment: Where did you get the G41 anyway, from some utility program or just from the model name?

Answer (score 1):

One chipset it for control of the motherboard and processor, while the other is dedicated to processing graphics.

[Intel® G41 Express Chipset](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/mainstream-chipsets/g41-express-chipset.html)

[Intel® Z87 Chipset Platform](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/performance-chipsets/z87-chipset.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your motherboard have nothing to do with chipset G41. G41 is something of the Core2 age. Having "G41" in the model name doesn't mean it uses that chip.